# Alter sequence from a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, triggers

I have an auto increment trigger that goes something like as follows

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_auto_inc
  BEFORE INSERT ON TESTTABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.TestCol IS NULL THEN
    SELECT Auto_Increment.nextval INTO :new.TestCol FROM dual;
  END IF;
END;
```

and I want to add in an if statement that will somehow lead to a decrement in the sequence I am using which is as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Auto_Increment START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 100;
```

I need to decrement the count somehow like this

```
ALTER SEQUENCE Auto_Increment INCREMENT BY -1;
SELECT Auto_Increment.NEXTVAL FROM dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE Auto_Increment INCREMENT BY 1;
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect you have an XY problem....

Answer (score 2):

That's most probably not a good idea. What real problem are you trying to solve?

---

Anyway, as you asked, here's one option which does that.

This is what you currently have:

```
SQL> create table testtable (testcol number, datum date);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence auto_increment start with 1 increment by 1 cache 100;

Sequence created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger test_auto_inc
  2    before insert on testtable
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_seq number;
  6  begin
  7    l_seq := auto_increment.nextval;
  8    if l_seq >= 3 then
  9       execute immediate 'alter sequence auto_increment increment by -1';
 10       l_seq := auto_increment.nextval;
 11       execute immediate 'alter sequence auto_increment increment by 1';
 12    end if;
 13
 14    :new.testcol := nvl(:new.testcol, l_seq);
 15  end;
 16  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into testtable (datum) values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into testtable (datum) values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from testtable order by datum;

   TESTCOL DATUM
---------- -------------------
         1 20.03.2022 08:22:17
         2 20.03.2022 08:22:26

SQL>
```

---

If you want to modify (alter, eh?) the sequence within a PL/SQL procedure (that's your trigger), you'll have to use **dynamic SQL** as this is the only way to run a DDL from PL/SQL. OK, let's add it (I also slightly modified your code; no need for `select` while fetching sequence value):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger test_auto_inc
  2    before insert on testtable
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_seq number;
  6  begin
  7    l_seq := auto_increment.nextval;
  8    if l_seq >= 3 then
  9       execute immediate 'alter sequence auto_increment increment by -1';
 10       l_seq := auto_increment.nextval;
 11       execute immediate 'alter sequence auto_increment increment by 1';
 12    end if;
 13
 14    :new.testcol := nvl(:new.testcol, l_seq);
 15  end;
 16  /

Trigger created.
```

Nice, it compiled! Why wouldn't it, Oracle has no idea what's written between single quotes. Could've been the 1st statement from Moby Dick. Let's try it:

```
SQL> insert into testtable (datum) values (sysdate);
insert into testtable (datum) values (sysdate)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TEST_AUTO_INC", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TEST_AUTO_INC'


SQL>
```

Whooops! Can't commit in a trigger. Bummer! Is there a way out of it? Certainly - declare the trigger to be an autonomous transaction:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger test_auto_inc
  2    before insert on testtable
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  6    l_seq number;
  7  begin
  8    l_seq := auto_increment.nextval;
  9    if l_seq >= 3 then
 10       execute immediate 'alter sequence auto_increment increment by -1';
 11       l_seq := auto_increment.nextval;
 12       execute immediate 'alter sequence auto_increment increment by 1';
 13    end if;
 14
 15    :new.testcol := nvl(:new.testcol, l_seq);
 16  end;
 17  /

Trigger created.
```

Does it work? Yes!

```
SQL> insert into testtable (datum) values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from testtable order by datum;

   TESTCOL DATUM
---------- -------------------
         1 20.03.2022 08:22:17
         2 20.03.2022 08:22:26
         3 20.03.2022 08:26:55

SQL>
```

Yet another insert:

```
SQL> insert into testtable (datum) values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from testtable order by datum;

   TESTCOL DATUM
---------- -------------------
         1 20.03.2022 08:22:17
         2 20.03.2022 08:22:26
         3 20.03.2022 08:26:55
         3 20.03.2022 08:27:31       --> see? Yet another testcol = 3!

SQL>
```

---

So, yes ... it can be done. Note, though, that if you used autonomous transaction within a trigger for purposes different from logging, you're most probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Excellent explanation and example